# mod rewrite not showing content on 2nd level links

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hello I have a mod_rewrite script for seo friendly urls on a personal site that I built. This script was wroking great until I noticed I could not accsess my admin folder which is a real directory on the server. The .htacsess look like this before I made my first change.

---

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

---

so I modified the script and added a second set of these two rules:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

directly before the last rule so it looked like this without the first 4 lines of code:

```
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

---

Once I did this I was able to accsess the admin directory but now the content will not display on the 2nd level links so it looks like the last rule is being ignored.

Can anybody help me see what I am doing wrong I would be very greatful.

Ryan Bauer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the second rule. If you really want it to work, it should be 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1/$2`, because the second `(.*)` isn't part of `$1`.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. are you saying I remove the last three rules and replace it with the new rule you listed becasue the wildcard should cover the second level links?

Comment: I'm saying that you should only need the first four rules, up to and including `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1`. However, if that doesn't work, keep *all* of the rules you have, and replace the last rule with `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1/$2`. In other words, add `/$2` to the last rule after `$1`.

Comment: thank you when I tried doing what you said including adding the /$2 the server could no longer display the fist level links the second level links still displays the page but the content from the db did not display. It's kinda wierd because the page displays with all the css the only thing that is not displaying is the content that is pulled from the server

Comment: I think I see the problem. Try adding `RewriteBase /` before everything else. You should keep all of the other rules the same, including the `?page=$1/$2` part. Also, you may want to try adding `[L,QSA]` after both of the `RewriteRule`s.

Comment: I have found a work around it might not be exactly how I thought I might change it but it works none the less. I found a rule to just ignore that one directory not all existing directories. I added this line of code after the second rule:

RewriteRule ^admin - [L,NC]


the above will match any URI beginning admin.

 - The - means do nothing.
 - The L means this should be last rule; ignore everything following.
 - The NC means no-case (so "ADMIN" is also matched).

Comment: Did you try the `RewriteBase` line? It doesn't sound like what you've found is what you're looking for. Specifically, what you've found (should) perform absolutely no redirection at all for the admin folder. Perhaps I've misunderstood your requirements, but that doesn't sound like what you were looking for.